# AWS SES 400 Bad Request response with Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5

I am trying to use the Amazon SES driver with Laravel 5.2 My access keys are setup and the sdk installed.

When I go to send an email I get this error:

```
SesException in WrappedHttpHandler.php line 159:
Error executing "SendRawEmail" on "https://email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
<Error>
<Type>Sender</Type>
<Code>InvalidPara (truncated...)
InvalidParameterValue (client): Illegal address - <ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
<Error>
<Type>Sender</Type>
<Code>InvalidParameterValue</Code>
<Message>Illegal address</Message>
</Error>
<RequestId>c3f0fcdf-d518-11e5-9d69-19428e2d926c</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

This is my first time trying to use this and can't seem to find any solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like the `from` address is invalid or not one of your SES account's verified sending addresses.

Comment: @ceejayoz Good point! Now I get: `<Error>
<Type>Sender</Type>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>Signature expired: 20160217T022013Z is now earlier than 20160217T022046Z (20160217T022546Z - 5 min.)</Message>
</Error>
<RequestId>c0aeb0d9-d51d-11e5-b28f-99d3cd5b3aec</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>`

Comment: Check that your server's time is correct.

Comment: @ceejayoz You're a legend. Currently running on a local dev vm so the time was off. I ran `/usr/sbin/ntpdate pool.ntp.org` and it's sorted. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help. :-)

Comment: Me getting this:  resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: Sender SenderInvalidChangeBatch[RRSet with DNS nam

Answer (score 4):

I know this question has been resolved in the question comments themselves but I'm place this answer here to help others who may run into this problem and may have alternative problems.

I recently ran into this problem as well. I was using a specific IAM User to send emails via SES and this IAM User was not the owner of the Sending Domain.

The Source Email Address and Return Path Email Address were both in the Sending Domain.

This required setting the SourceArn and ReturnPathArn to the Arn of the Identity that Owned the Sending Domain in the SendEmail Call.